# How to call a static method from a Django model "backward link"?

Tags: python, django, orm, foreign-keys

These are my two Django Models, `MyModelB` has a foreign key to `MyModelA`:

```
from django.db import models


class MyModelA(models.Model):
    my_int = models.IntegerField()

    def __str__(self):
        return "MyModelA #%s: my_int=%s" % (
            self.pk,
            self.my_int,
        )

class MyModelB(models.Model):
    my_int = models.IntegerField()
    my_a = models.ForeignKey(MyModelA, related_name="MyModelB_a")

    def __str__(self):
        return "MyModelB #%s: my_int=%s" % (
            self.pk,
            self.my_int,
        )

    @staticmethod
    def my_static_method():
        return "Hello"
```

I create an instance of `MyModelA` and `MyModelB`:

```
>>> a = MyModelA(my_int=20)
>>> a.save()
>>> a
<MyModelA: MyModelA #3: my_int=20>

>>> b = MyModelB(my_int=30, my_a=a)
>>> b.save()
>>> b
<MyModelB: MyModelB #3: my_int=30>
```

From the instance of `MyModelA`, I can reference the `MyModelB` using "reverse-links":

```
>>> a.MyModelB_a.filter(my_int=30)
[<MyModelB: MyModelB #3: my_int=30>]
```

But I want to call `MyModelB.my_static_method()` from the instance of `MyModelA`. How can I do it? My attempted solution doesn't work:

```
>>> a.MyModelB_a.my_static_method()
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<console>", line 1, in <module>
AttributeError: 'RelatedManager' object has no attribute 'my_static_method'
>>>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll have to access the model class in order to call the static method.

Use `a.MyModelB_a.model.my_static_method()`

The `model` attribute returns the model class `MyModelB`.